# Laravel Carbon subtract days from current date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am trying to extract objects from Model "Users" whose `created_at` date has been more than **30 days from today**.

Carbon::now() ==> I want as ==> Carbon::now() - 30days

```
$users = Users::where('status_id', 'active')
               ->where( 'created_at', '<', Carbon::now())
               ->get();
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Use [`subDays()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method:

```
$users = Users::where('status_id', 'active')
           ->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
           ->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure about changing '<' to '>' for getting users created more than 30 days ago?

Comment: my condition is that current date is more than 30 days from current date. I guess this logic does the task for me

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin That's what the original asker is looking for; using today as an example (December 13th), "more than 30 days from today" would be users created before November 13th.

Comment: I guess his `more` means `later` here. Also `Carbon::now() ==> I want as ==> Carbon::now() - 30days` pretty much explains what OP wants.

Comment: Aah yes... sorry I guess I was not clear. Yes "later" is what i meant

Comment: subDays(30) is correct but I think it should be < to get users created more than 30 days ago. Upvoted the answer anyway because of correct method.

Comment: The answer doesn't need to be changed because subDays() subtract days. For example, today is 24-Nov-2019 and subDays(30) would return the date 24-Oct-2019. Thus if the comparison is < (less than) the result would be **all** records prior from 24-Oct-2019 but what OP want is later from that date and only want **30-day records**.
The answer is perfect!

Comment: As a note to remember you should reset H M S also to 00:00:00 or you are going to get the time difference against a Timestamp / Date Time field. so add `->endOfDay()` or `->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0)` or in the date setup `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')`

Comment: Are you sure it's not '<'

Answer (score 17):

From Laravel 5.6 you can use [whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries):

```
$users = Users::where('status_id', 'active')
       ->whereDate( 'created_at', '>', now()->subDays(30))
       ->get();
```

You also have whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear / whereTime

Comment: I like this one since it's using the now() helper.

Answer (score 9):

You can always use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to minus the number of days from the current date:

```
$users = Users::where('status_id', 'active')
           ->where( 'created_at', '>', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"))
           ->get();
```

Comment: could make it `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime("-30 days")` to be more tidy

Answer (score 2):

As with strtotime or DateTime, any (relative) date expressions can also be used with `carbon::parse`.

```
$users = Users::where('status_id', 'active')
           ->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::parse('Now -30 days'))
           ->get();
```

Alternatively for 'Now -30 Days', expressions '-30days' or '-720 hours' are also possible.

'Now -30 Days' takes into account the current time. If you need a time 00:00, use 'Today -30 Days'.